# nodejs create directory in sync way is not reliable

Tags: node.js

I am using following code to create directories in sync way. It checks the existence of the directory, deletes it if exists and creates it. All operations are in sync way. I am looping this operation for 5 times. I am getting different results each time. Sometimes it creates only 4 directories, sometimes it creates all 5. What is the reason for this unstability in the code?

```
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, filenames) {
    if (err) {
        onError(err);
        return;
    }
    filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
        fs.readFile(dir + filename, 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
            if (err) {
                onError(err);
                return;
            }
            AsyncFunc(content, ....)
                .then(newContent => {

   filenames.forEach(function(filename) {

      if (fs.existsSync(currentDirName)) {
                fs.rmdirSync(currentDirName);
         }

      fs.mkdirSync(currentDirName, '0766');

          });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using sync functions you can not use callbacks. Also if you want to remove a folder you need to use `rmdirSync(filename);`

```
var fs = require('fs');
var filenames = ['1','2','3','4'];

filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
  if (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
    fs.rmdirSync(filename);
  }
  fs.mkdirSync(filename, '0766');
});
```

Comment: I tried but still the same issue is there :( Then I tried with your filnames array and it worked

Comment: No error, what I am doing it reading all files in a directory and for each file, create a directory and generate other set of files. I will update my code illustrating the source of my loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176808/discussion-between-malintha-and-hurricane).